# find the length of the input string

Tags: assembly, mips

This is what I got so far. What can I fix to get this right?

```
.data
msg1:.asciiz "Please insert text (max 20 characters): "
msg2:.asciiz "\nThe length of the text is: "

newline: .asciiz "\n"

str1: .space 20
.text
.globl main
main:
addi $v0, $v0,4
la $a0,msg1
syscall #print msg1
li $v0,8
la $a0,str1
addi $a1,$zero,20
syscall   #get string 1

la $a0,str1  #pass address of str1
jal len

len: 
## your code here
addi $t2, $zero, 0 # $t2 is what we want to return in the end -- the count of the length of the character array
addi $s1, $zero, 0 # Index i for array traversing | init. to 0 | i = 0

Loop:

add $s1, $s1, $a0 # Adds the location of the index to the location of the base of the array | $t1 is now the location of: array[index]
lw $t0, 0($s1)

beq $t0, $zero, exit
addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Count = Count + 1
addi $s1, $s1, 1 # i = i + 1
j Loop

exit: 
la $a0,msg2 
li $v0,4
syscall
move $a0,$t0 #output the results 
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please keep in mind, that you always provide *all* relevant information that we need to help you with your problem. Your question is lacking in the following areas: What *exactly* do you want it to do, what does it do now, what did you expect instead? Please use the edit button below your post to supply the additional information. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
add $s1, $s1, $a0
```

Here, you overwrite $s1, so adding 1 to $s1 is not correct anymore. Just initialize $s1 with the address of the string (instead of 0) and remove this line.

```
lw $t0, 0($s1)
```

This should be `lb`. You're loading a byte, not 4 bytes.